# Is it correct to say 'someone other than they two'?

Tags: grammaticality, pronouns

Here's the full sentence:

> Sarah was upset that *someone other than they two* knew where the
> treasure was.

I don't even know how to phrase this question, but the phrase in italic sounds wrong and I don't know what it is that is wrong. I've tried to enter this phrase into Google and noting pops up to kind of direct my research. Is this correct, and if it isn't, what's the best way to rewrite this sentence?

Comment: “Those two” would be good.

Comment: @Xanne The intention is to create a reflexive; Sarah was upset that she and the other person were not the only ones with the said information.

Comment: It's a bit old fashioned, that's all, and maybe a bit literary, but no harm in that. "“If they two are in heaven?” Quick was the little Maid's reply,. “O Master! we are seven.” “But they are dead; those two are dead! Their spirits are in heaven!” - _We are Seven_ (poem, 1798) by William Wordsworth

Comment: _We too are one_ was considered a viable punning album title in the 1980s by the Eurythmics.

Comment: Sarah was upset that *someone else* knew where the treasure was.

Comment: If they three are not here, who will teach us the way to Heaven? - John Paton  (1896)

Comment: It's not obvious to me why *other than **they** [small number]* is relatively uncommon compared to [*other than you two*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22other+than+you+two%22) and [*other than we three*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22other+than+we+three%22), but obviously it's exactly the same syntax, so *in principle*, it's fine.

Answer (score 2):

"Other than they two"  seems to be idiomatic enough.  ([examples](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22other+than+they+two%22&sca_esv=563061816&tbm=bks&ei=yG_4ZInwH8q7kdUP1NmVmAs&start=0&sa=N&ved=2ahUKEwiJ9LW9_ZWBAxXKXaQEHdRsBbM4FBDy0wN6BAgBEAQ&biw=546&bih=569&dpr=1.75))

However, the suggestion that has been made in the comments (those two) does not appear to have the quality of being the perfectly neutral wording that appears to be needed. I'd suggest something else: "*other than the two of them*".

- Sarah was upset that someone other than the two of them knew where the treasure was.

> ([ref.](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/380892-were-there-any-pyr-in-dc-other-than-the-two)) Deborah Cooke — 'Were there any Pyr in DC other than the two of them? No! It couldn't be! Raffery spun again, but Thorolf was keeping a wary distance.

Comment: "not found in the books"? I easily found [dozens of written instances.](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22other+than+they+two%22)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Not quite two dozens (19 instances), but that is quite enough; moreover there are the cases of the variant "other than us two" which confirm the general form. I see my error now: my research was  restrictive beyond what common sense asked for; "someone" should not have been included; that is why I had no results.

Comment: Strictly speaking, *other than **us** two* is the "informal, colloquial" version of [*other than **we** two*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=other+than+us+three%2Cother+than+we+three&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=20&case_insensitive=true), so it's no surprise Google Books reports more matches for the "correct" form in published written contexts. Myself, I  wouldn't hesitate to say *Other than **them** two...* in informal spoken contexts, but *Other than **they** two...* definitely doesn't occur that often, even though it's syntactically unexceptional.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I suppose that you consider "us" informal in the context of subject case, as in the OP's sentence. As I see this point of grammar, if the pronoun is the complement of a preposition (with) or an object, "us" would be the proper form. That is, as applied to the first two cases of the page you mention ("About how difficult it's going to be to have any sort of permanent relationship with people other than us three.”, 
"No words have been said here that anyone, other than us three, can understand."), "us" is only colloquial in the second one, where the subject case  points to "we".

Comment: I didn't think of it at the time, but yes - you're quite right about the different subject/object contexts.

Answer (score 2):

It is not grammatically wrong, but it is rather awkward.  I think most native speakers would say something like

> Sarah was upset that someone other than *the two of them* knew where the treasure was

Comment: You've just duplicated what the other answer has already suggested, except with less explanation.

Comment: Thank you, @ColleenV, that is very helpful.

Comment: Well I thought it was more helpful than downvoting without comment. What is the point of repeating exactly what someone else has already answered?

Comment: Also "other than them two" when spoken would definitely sound correct to a native speaker, which is the ultimate test of grammatical correctness. "They two" in the original sounds wrong and would indicate to me a non-native speaker (written or spoken) even if it may be correct according to grammatical rules.

Answer (score 0):

Another [idiomatic version](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=other%20than%20me%2Cother%20than%20us%2C%20other%20than%20her%2C%20other%20than%20them&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) would be **someone other than *them*** although in many prescriptive grammars that would be flagged as incorrect and it would be asserted that a subject-case (nominative) is required.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the demonstrative pronoun **those** or **these**:

> someone other than **those** two

*These* are closer than *those*, physically or in your mind.  “**These** two” implies that they are the same people you were thinking about immediately before you said that, or that they are right there.